# Access learned weights within iteration - keras or tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

After approx 1000 iterations and frequency of approx 20 iterations I see the acc and val_acc increase from 0 for a single iteration , then returning to 0 for next iteration :

```
5s - loss: 2.0677 - acc: 0.1345 - val_loss: 3.0170 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 180/3000

5s - loss: 2.0821 - acc: 0.1426 - val_loss: 3.0052 - val_acc: 0.6520
Epoch 181/3000

5s - loss: 2.0755 - acc: 0.1202 - val_loss: 3.0405 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

As I want to learn weight where `val_cc` is greater > 50% can I access weight parameters at specific iteration , in this case when `acc` is 0.1426 and `val_acc` is 0.6520 ?

Alternative does keras support saving model weights when specified `acc` & `val_acc` conditions are me ?

Update :

After decreasing learning rate :

```
Epoch 7562/300000
1s - loss: 0.7599 - acc: 0.6968 - val_loss: 0.2335 - val_acc: 0.9231
Epoch 7563/300000
1s - loss: 0.7484 - acc: 0.7119 - val_loss: 0.3115 - val_acc: 0.8828
Epoch 7564/300000
1s - loss: 0.7702 - acc: 0.6980 - val_loss: 0.3340 - val_acc: 0.8388
```

Comment: What are you using to create the training iteration? It should be pretty straight forward to save the weights at any iteration.  But be careful, If your accuracy is around 0.14 and your validation acurracy had a sudden spike this is almost 100% chance of it being an accident and that it would not help you to have those weights.

Comment: If your model reached a plato of improvement then you should try tweeking the hyperparameters for better results. Try lowering the learning rate.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLazari thanks, excluding the sudden spike if there is a consistent discrepancy where the training accuracy is lower than validation accuracy does this suggest over-fitting ? If training accuracy was .65 and validation accuracy .85 does this suggest an adequately trained model as the validation accuracy is so high, despite the training accuracy being .65 ?

Comment: The classic sign of overfitting is when validation loss starts starts to rise. By design the training loss will always lower, But when it lowers but does not help performance on your validation set that is your model overfitting to your training set. What you are mentioning is very strange. the val_acc is higher than the train_acc?!? Is this happening every time you run the model? (my best guess would be that your validation set is "leaking" to your training set somehow.) Make sure there are no duplicate examples between validation and training sets.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLazari please see update, perhaps training and validation accuracies will balance eventually. Good point about the duplicates between validation and training sets, will check also for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can manage to save your model using the callback api of Keras. You have to create your `callback` class and implement the function `on_epoch_end()` save your model depending on the conditions you want.
I think the best option is to check the implementation of `ModelCheckpoint`. You can check it in the [doc](https://keras.io/callbacks/)